# How to set values to text box after selecting from select box using json jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

Below is my servlet Controller for json

Controller.java

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

@WebServlet("/Controller") public class Controller extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

                PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();  
               JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            ArrayList<StockBean> l=m.items();


            for(int i=0;i<l.size();i++)
            {
                String name=l.get(i).getIname();
                int qty=l.get(i).getIquantity();
                json.put("name",qty);
            }

            out.print(json);
            } }
```

And below is the JSP code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('#itemid').change(function(){
        var $country=$("#itemid").val();
        $.ajax({  
            url:'Controller',  
            type:'post',  
            dataType: 'json', 
            success: function(data) { 

                $('#cq').val(data.name);  

            }  
        });  
    });  
});          
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>UPDATE STOCK</h1>
<form action="AddStockInt.jsp" method="post">
 <table width="400">

 <% Model m = new Model();
     ArrayList<StockBean> s= m.items();
   %>
  <tr>
    <td><lable>Item Name:</lable> </td>
     <td><select id="itemid" name="cname">

<%for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++){ %>

<option style=margin:35px;><%=s.get(i).getIname() %></option>

<%} %>
</select>
</td>

  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td><lable>Current Qty:</lable></td>

  <td><input type="text" id="cq" name="cqty" style=margin:5px;/></td>

  </tr>
```

All the data for select box name "cname" and text box name "cqty" is coming dynamically, so I want to set the data to the text box name "cqty" automatically after selecting the value from select box name "cname" but my javascript (jQuery)  code is not selecting ie. I am not understanding to write key value code in javacript (jQuery) while calling the ajax, please help me on the same.

Answer (score 0):

on changing dropdown its value reflects in the text box

Please have a look at this api ; her inside "data" Array there are both id and first name; We are choosing id from dropdown and corresponding first Name appears.

```js
$("#sbox").on('change',() => {  
  $.ajax({
   'url' : 'https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2',
   success : function(data) {
      let dropdownvalue = $("#sbox").val();
      let object = data["data"].filter((obj) => {
        return obj["id"] == dropdownvalue;
      })
      let name = object[0]["first_name"];
      let result = `Your Id from dropdown -- ${dropdownvalue} corresponds to the name -- ${name}`;
      $("#result").html(result);
   }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sbox">
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
</select>

<div>
change dropdown to see Corresponding name below value here
</div>
<div id="result">
</div>
```

Comment: if i use $('#cq').html(data.name); i am not getting any output ie output is coming empty

Comment: please help to get quantity for each name and automatically display the quantity in text box for each name selection

Comment: @Niteen I think i know what went wrong for you. $("#cq) will return an array.; you have to do $("#cq")[0]; Look at my answer

Comment: my requirement is i have one select box and one text box and based on the value from select box the value should appear in text box automatically

Comment: @Niteen I just noticed a few issues with your script; your ajax post request is not dependent on change in dropdown, then why is your script running with change function; Also put console.log(data) inside success and tell me what it says.

Comment: @ rajkumar my requirement is i have one select box and one text box and based on the value from select box the value should appear in text box automatically  Please note the json object in my servlet is selecting value from database as mentioned  in the above servlet code and also the values available in the select box are also from database which acts as a key in json object ,upon selecting the key value should come automatically in text box ie upon triggering the change event of select box value should be apprear in text box please help to write the jquery code for the same

Comment: Still i am not bale to execute it

Comment: @ rajkumar,dude sorry for troubling you but i am new to the Json and ajax and jquery so i have the above mentioned requirement for ajax call ,i guess you know my requirements could you please help me with some example for above scenario.

Comment: correct me if am wrong (1) you choose from dropdown (2) based on choice an ajax call will be made (3) response must be put in the input box..

is this what u want?

Comment: yes correct and also the response in input box is from database suppose     values in database

item name   quantity

A                  10  

B                  20               

C                  30  

D                 40             here select box should have values A,B,C and D and when u chose A from select box 10 should come in input box,when select B from select box 20 should come in input box and so on...

Comment: the colsole.log(data) is printing as {A: 10, B: 20, C: 30, D: 40}